# ssh issue in a loop

Tags: shell, ssh

I have a script that connects to a server using `ssh`. While in a loop, it fails to connect to the second server after connecting to the first one. I guess I have to quit from that server to come back to the calling script. How do I quit the ssh session?

```
while read dbname myip
do
ssh root@$myip "mysqldump - some command " | mysql -hhost -u -p myLocalDatabase > /dev/null 2>&1
done << iplist
db1 111.111.111.111
xyz 222.222.222.222
iplist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

redirect stdin to /dev/null

```
while  read -r dbname myip
do
 0</dev/null ssh ...... <whatever> .........
done < "iplist"
```

Answer (score 1):

At a slightly higher level of abstraction, you may be interested in e.g. [Chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home):

> Chef is a systems integration framework, built to bring the benefits of configuration management to your entire infrastructure. With Chef, you can:
>
> - Manage your servers by writing code, not by running commands. (via Cookbooks)
> - Integrate tightly with your applications, databases, LDAP directories, and more. (via Libraries)
> - Easily configure applications that require knowledge about your entire infrastructure ("What systems are running my application?" "What is the current master database server?")

Answer (score 0):

If you want to issue the same command on multiple SSH hosts, you can use [DSH](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html.en):

> dsh is an implementation of a wrapper for executing multiple remote shell (rsh/remsh/ssh) commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have whitespace in the lines of file "dbname", you can use this:

```
for myip in $(cat dbname); do
   ...
done
```

(or use fabric: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/)